# Rigid body in player add velocity to it

Tags: rust, bevy, rapier-3d

I have the following function that well spawn my player and adds a little physics to it rigid body and so on

```
fn spawn_player(mut commands: Commands, assets: Res<AssetServer>) {
    let player = (
        SceneBundle {
            scene: assets.load("beta.glb#Scene0"),
            transform: Transform::from_xyz(0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
            ..default()
        },
        Player,
        Speed {
            walk: 3.0,
            jump: 50.0,
        },
        ThirdPersonCameraTarget,
        Name::new("Player"),
    );

    commands
        .spawn(player)
        .insert(RigidBody::Dynamic)
        .insert(Collider::cuboid(1.0, 1.0, 1.0))
        .insert(ColliderMassProperties::Density(2.0))
        .insert(TransformBundle::from(Transform::from_xyz(0.0, 5.0, 0.0)))
        .insert(Sleeping::disabled())
        .insert(Velocity {
            linvel: Vec3::new(1.0, 0.0, 0.0),
            angvel: Vec3::new(0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
        })
        .insert(Ccd::enabled())
        .insert(GravityScale(0.5));
}
```

But the thing is in the docs it states that you cannot directly alternate the position of the rigid body

```
fn player_movement(
    keys: Res<Input<KeyCode>>,
    time: Res<Time>,
    mut player_q: Query<(&mut Transform, &Speed), With<Player>>,
    cam_q: Query<&Transform, (With<Camera3d>, Without<Player>)>,
) {
    for (mut player_transform, player_speed) in player_q.iter_mut() {
        let cam = match cam_q.get_single() {
            Ok(c) => c,
            Err(e) => Err(format!("Erro pegando o objeto de camera: {}", e)).unwrap(),
        };
        let mut direction: Vec3 = Vec3::ZERO;
        if keys.pressed(KeyCode::W) {
            direction += cam.forward();
            direction.y = 0.0;
        }
        if keys.pressed(KeyCode::S) {
            direction += cam.back();
            direction.y = 0.0;
        }
        if keys.pressed(KeyCode::A) {
            direction += cam.left();
            direction.y = 0.0;
        }
        if keys.pressed(KeyCode::D) {
            direction += cam.right();
            direction.y = 0.0;
        }
        if keys.pressed(KeyCode::Space) {
            direction += cam.up();
        }
        if keys.pressed(KeyCode::A)
            || keys.pressed(KeyCode::S)
            || keys.pressed(KeyCode::D)
            || keys.pressed(KeyCode::W)
        {
            let movement: Vec3 =
                direction.normalize_or_zero() * player_speed.walk * time.delta_seconds();
            player_transform.translation += movement;
        } else {
            let movement: Vec3 =
                direction.normalize_or_zero() * player_speed.jump * time.delta_seconds();
            player_transform.translation += movement;
        }

        if direction.length_squared() > 0.0 {
            player_transform.look_to(direction, Vec3::Y)
        }
    }
}
```

In this case the rigid body is accompanying the player BUT I am not sure if I am teleporting it or moving it (adding velocity to it). Can someone explain how the insert function works?

Comment: Pretty sure you need to modify the [`Velocity`](https://docs.rs/bevy_rapier3d/latest/bevy_rapier3d/dynamics/struct.Velocity.html) instead.